# Dual extensions in a filename? *.css.php 404

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress plugin Easy FancyBox.
It uses a dynamic php file for it's CSS.
The problem is that my server gives a 404 when trying to access the file, I think because of the dual extensions. The filename is easy-fancybox.css.php
The plugin was working perfectly until I switched servers. Is there a config somewhere where I can allow this?

Turns out I can't access any .php file, so it's not the double extension thing, lol oops.
I still don't know why though.

Comment: Usually the system uses the last extension as the file's actual extension, being `easy-fancybox.css` would be the name of the file, and `.php` would be the extension. You can make it `somefile.htaccess.css.jpeg.tar.gz.php`, it's still a PHP file.

Comment: There's nothing to allow. the file name is easy-fancybox.css and the extension is .PHP. It's a perfectly normal filename. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I know this should work, and normally does, but to test it I made two files: something.css & something.css.php    the first was 200OK, second was 404

Comment: Please, upload the file first =D

Comment: Lol. >_>
.htaccess files look different, I'll mess with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours I finally fixed it.
File permissions had to be 755 on the file. I had them at 775. I don't know why it's set up like this, but I found the answer here: [IN Wordpress, .php files within the theme folder do not run, but return 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195252/in-wordpress-php-files-within-the-theme-folder-do-not-run-but-return-404-erro)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain but check that you've transfered the .htaccess as well,

that might be the problem

Comment: .htaccess were different, but they're now the same, and it still doesn't work.



    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php
    </IfModule>
    
    # END WordPress

Comment: The full .htaccess contains just this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry the formatting is crap.. Turns out I can't access any .php file directly.